# Why do I get "cache: [GET /] miss" in production using WebRick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, webrick

I cannot test my website in production mode using WebRick, as it is raising cache errors. In development and testing modes everything works perfectly.

I have set this option in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

And then I ran:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Now I start up the server:

```
david$ rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-01-31 19:52:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-01-31 19:52:35] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
[2012-01-31 19:52:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13329 port=3000
```

And when I go to http://localhost:3000 I get "We're sorry, but something went wrong.". In the terminal this is what it outputs:

```
cache: [GET /] miss
```

I'm stalled here. I have no clue in what to do.

Comment: Did you changed the `config.cache_store` in application.rb ?

Comment: No, the application is new, I have not touched that file.

Comment: Ok. Is there an error in the `production.log` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the asset pipeline, which has to be well configured in production mode, as files are not precompiled automatically.

In my case, I was inserting a javascript file (with `javascript_include_tag`) that was only present in one page, so it was not included in the application.js manifest.

In that case, the asset pipeline is not precompiling the file when running `assets:precompile`.

In order to include the missing file, we have to edit `config/environments/production.rb` and add this line:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( script1.js )
```

You will notice that this line already exists, but it's commented. Read the comment for more clarification. For more info, look at the [official asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets).

Answer (score 0):

This message about missing pages sends Rack::Cache middleware. 
If you dont need to use page caching in your rails app,  just remove Rack::Cache in config/application.rb file:

```
require 'rack/cache'

module DemoApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.delete Rack::Cache
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvote - but telling the OP not to use a feature doesn't solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

As provisional solution, the following made the trick for me.

I changed the `config/environments/production.rb` file to change `config.assets.compile` line from `false` to `true`

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
 config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To run application in production so you don't get cache: [GET /] miss
Please Check you **{project}/public** folder , is their any assets folder exists
if not then pre compile assets using
             **bundle exec rake assets:precompile**

once this is done :

set **config.assets.compile** to  **true** in production.rb

Then restart you WebApp in production environment .

This approch worked for me hope will work for you .

If you are using rails 3.2.0 you will get [GET /] miss , but your application will work properly .